# How to set the address of a function in C in a specific memory location

Tags: c++, c

since I am using embedded system, I need to store a specific function in an external memory location in the address 0x840140

Here is the function:

```
//The function that I want to set its address to 0x840140
float myfunction(float x,float y) {
  float z;
  z=x+y;
  return z;
 }


 void main() {
  float w;
  //Calling the function
 w=myfunction(5.5,10.5);      
 }
```

Comment: This is imppossible to answer generically, as there is no standard that defines how functions or code in general is located in memory in C or C++. What compiler are you using? What linker? Is 0x840140 a virtual or physical address?

Comment: Why you want to set the address to specific 0x840140?. In other words what do you want to achieve it from this?

Comment: Do you really need to place this particular function at this address, or do you just need to match the address range? You can usually specify where the linker should place specific symbol addresses using a linker map file as additional input. If you need to target specific address vectors (e.g. exception handlers), you should also attribute your function properly (naked).

Comment: Thanks Mantosh 
I am using xilinx SDK development kit from xilinx
The problem is that, the external memory is about 64 MB
And the internal the memory is about 16 KB
And I cannot store any extra function in the internal memory

Comment: Not only this function
But at least 5 other functions

Comment: And yes the address 0x840140 is a physical memory location

Comment: @user3553884 _'But at least 5 other functions'_ Then check out my hint about the linker map file ...

Comment: Usually the linker assigns addresses to objects.  You are going to need to use the linker language, if your tool chain has one, to override the default linker behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Xilinx "MicroBlaze" seems to be using a GNU CC based compiler, which means it (probably) using the gnu ld linker. It has a fairly extensive [scripting language](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html), so different sections of code, for example, can be located at different locations.

If you don't want ALL of your code to be located as one lump, you will need to "set" a section for the function in question, e.g:

```
void myfunction (void) __attribute__ ((section ("at840000.text")));
```

then use `text.at840000` to tell the linker where you want the code to be placed.

Something like this:

```
SECTIONS {
  at840000.text 0x840000 { * }
}
```

(I'm not 100% sure about the exact syntax here, but something along those lines)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no never tried this.

It might be possible using a linker script. [This article](http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/82710718100/kernel-101-lets-write-a-kernel) places code at a specific address for building a kernel. Check the section about "The linking part".

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want the function stored in a specific memory location? You probably want just the function result.

```
void main() {
  float *w = (float*)0x840140;
  //Calling the function
  *w=myfunction(5.5,10.5);      
}
```

This will put the float returned by myFunction() in the correct memory location.

Comment: I don't think this answers what the OP asked for.

Comment: No 
My question is clear, I want to enforce the compiler to store the whole function code in the location 0x840140

Comment: Reading from the other comments, It looks like you need a linker map. Xilinx has a GUI to help you with this: [http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_1/SDK_Doc/tasks/sdk_t_create_lscript.htm](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_1/SDK_Doc/tasks/sdk_t_create_lscript.htm)